# DrawingArc and PaintEventArgs issue (how to call this function)

Tags: c#, .net

```
private void Drawarc(PaintEventArgs  e)
{

    // Create pen.
    System.Windows.Media.Pen blackPen = new     
   System.Windows.Media.Pen(System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Black, 3);
    // Create rectangle to bound ellipse.
    Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Rectangle rect = new Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Rectangle(100, 
    100, 140, 140);
    // Create start and sweep angles on ellipse.
    float startAngle = 45.0F;
    float sweepAngle = 270.0F;
    // Draw arc to screen.
   //Graphics.DrawArc(blackPen, rect, startAngle, sweepAngle);
}
```

i am trying to call this  function like this

```
  this.Drawarc();
```

So it gives me the following error

No overload for method 'Drawarc' takes 0 arguments
i know i am doing something wrong  please help

Comment: You're not passing in an argument to this method when it requires one (see: `PaintEventArgs e`). You're not using the argument in the function though.. so remove `PaintEventArgs e` from the method and it will compile without error (whether the method works or not I'm not sure).

Answer (score 1):

```
private void Drawarc(PaintEventArgs  e) {
    ...
}
```

This function *clearly* expects `PaintEventArgs`  type object like a parameter. 
That kind of object is **usually** obtained inside Form's `OnPaint(...)` method.